Идентичность записей строк с указателем и массивом
Является ли запись строки
const char* str = "hello";

идентичной этой?
char arr[] = "hello";
const char* str = arr;


Не является. В первом случае строковый литерал попадёт в read-only область данных и его нельзя изменять.
Во втором случае появляется символьный массив arr[6] с элементами: h, e, l, l, o, \0. Этот массив можно изменить.
